# When is the onyomi reading " ゾウ " for the kanji 三 used?

Tags: kanji

The only example reading I could find for ゾウ is on Jisho.org where 三蔵 ( さんぞう ) is actually using the "サン” reading for 三.
What is the point of having ゾウ as a reading for 三? When is it used?

Comment: Isn't that a name reading? Could be just a mistake to put it in the on'yomi category. It's not like the database Jisho uses for readings is authoritative. And not sure if it's related, since it's そう and not ぞう, but I live near 十三駅 (じゅうそうえき).

Comment: You might find [this other post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57702/the-yomikata-of-%e5%8d%81%e4%b8%89/57705#57705) useful for the background information on sound changes.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the quoted from [here](https://plaza.rakuten.co.jp/yohgo/diary/202009190000/) (emphasis mine). As suggested in the comment, it is a name reading.

【三】​（加納喜光「人名の漢字語源辞典」一部省略）​

​​​​［読み］音-サン（呉・漢）訓-み・みつ・みっつ​​​​

​​［語源］数詞の3の意味。これを横線三本を引いた図形で表記した。3の数は「多数」のイメージがあり、参（多くのものが入り交じる）・森（木がたくさん茂るさま）と同源。
​​
​​［人名読み］かず・さ・さぶ・さむ・さん・そ・そう・ぞう・ただ・み・みつ​​

**▽「さむ」「さぶ」「そう」は古音サム→サン→サウ→ソウから。**

♂ 上毛野三千 ﾐﾁ・淡海三船 ﾐﾂﾈ・藤原三守 ﾀﾀﾞﾓﾘ・ﾐﾓﾘ・八幡三郎 ｻﾌﾞﾛｳ
・斎藤道三 ﾄﾞｳｻﾝ・斎藤利三 ﾄｼﾐﾂ・石田三成 ﾐﾂﾅﾘ・柳生三厳 ﾐﾂﾖｼ
・森三樹三郎 ﾐｷｻﾌﾞﾛｳ・日下部伊三次 ｲｿｳｼﾞ・呉秀三 ｼｭｳｿﾞｳ・鈴木三重吉 ﾐｴｷﾁ
・武谷三男 ﾐﾂｵ・直木三十五 ｻﾝｼﾞｭｳｺﾞ・小林一三 ｲﾁｿﾞｳ・上田三四二 ﾐﾖｼﾞ
・小林与三次 ﾖｿｼﾞ・野口三千三 ﾐﾁｿﾞｳ・不破哲三 ﾃﾂｿﾞｳ・連城三紀彦 ﾐｷﾋｺ

​♀ 県犬養三千代 ﾐﾁﾖ・三位局 ｻﾝﾐﾉﾂﾎﾞﾈ・松原三穂子 ﾐﾎｺ・高峰三枝子 ﾐｴｺ
・嵯峨三智子 ﾐﾁｺ・青江三奈 ﾐﾅ​